# Update table only if count of rows of the same table is lower than a certain value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of people who have to confirm their assistance to an event. This event has limited capacity. I want to calculate the number of confirmed people and update the confirmation status within the same atomic query.

Let's say that PEOPLE table has id and confirmed fields.

I have tried something like this:

```sql
UPDATE PEOPLE
SET confirmed = 'Y'
WHERE
    id = 'ID_VALUE'
AND
    (
        SELECT amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*) AS amount
            FROM
                PEOPLE AS p
            WHERE
                p.confirmed = 'Y'
        ) AS aux1
    ) < CAPACITY_LIMIT
```

Example of table:

```
-------------------
| id  | confirmed |
-------------------
| 1   | N         |
-------------------
| 2   | N         |
-------------------
| ... | ...       |
-------------------
| 10  | N         |
-------------------
```

If CAPACITY_LIMIT = 5 and I try to confirm sequentially from id = 1 to id = 10, I want to perform the update (confirm = 'Y') until id = 5.

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I can't figure what is it.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: What is your current result? Do you get a error message or the wrong data?

Comment: I get 0 rows affected, looks like WHERE clause is not fulfilled

Comment: Do you have some example data and/or a table structure for me?

Comment: u dont need the outer select.

Comment: @palindrom If you don't put the outer select, you get this error: "SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'PEOPLE' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: what are you doing here `WHERE
    id = 'ID_VALUE'` ?

Comment: for debugging purpose add "cnt int" column to PEOPLE add set it like cnt = (select amount from (select count(*) from people p where p.confirmed = 'Y')aux1 ) when updating. see the values.

Comment: @BhavikShah I'm selecting the row that I want to update (confirm = 'Y')

Comment: @falvarez : then what is the use of `< CAPACITY_LIMIT`  anyways its gonna return 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    PEOPLE AS p1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numConfirmed FROM PEOPLE AS p2 WHERE p2.confirmed = 'Y') aux
SET
    p1.confirmed = 'Y'
WHERE
    p1.id = 'ID_VALUE'
    AND aux.numConfirmed < CAPACITY_LIMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SET @ct := (SELECT
                COUNT(*) AS amount
            FROM
                PEOPLE AS p
            WHERE
                p.confirmed = 'Y');
UPDATE PEOPLE
SET confirmed = 'Y'
WHERE
    id = '1'
AND CAPACITY_LIMIT < @ct
     ;
```

Comment: I don't know if the execution is atomic (no changes in the table between variable assignation and update)

Answer (score 0):

falvarez,
You might want to verify that your inputs('ID_VALUE',CAPACITY_LIMIT) are correct, including data type and actual value, since the same query works for me with no problem. The following is the query I run against my test table (as you can see the query skeleton is exactly same as yours):

update t_order set customer ='NewCustomerName' where id = 124 and 
(select amount from (select count(*) as amount from t_order where customer is not null) as total) < 10